# Ta-lib python STOCH indicator not storing data in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ta-lib

I am trying to store the output of the STOCH indicator in the dataframe, so that I can plot it later. Here is what I tried and what I got:

```
stock['slowk'],stock['slowd']=STOCH(stock, 5, 3, 0, 3, 0, timeperiod=5,prices=[ 'high', 'low', 'close'])
stock
```

I got the following output:

[image]

As you can see the values are not appearing or getting stored in the dataframe.

Without storing the values I am getting the numbers respectively as:
[image: image2]

Kindly, let me know what way I can store the output in the dataframe.

Editing Note:
I am using the Abstract API and not the Function API